# Indexing database for full text search with, Lucene/iFiler/SQL FTS/..etc

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, full-text-search, lucene.net

I have asked about the best algorithms/practices to perform full text search already and now I want to decide which to use. I have read about this topic thoroughly in the past few days but having no experience whatsoever, I still need help in figuring out the best tools for my needs, which is the aim of this question.

Points to consider:
1- I'm using C#.Net 2010 along with SQL Server 2008 R2, i.e i need a C#/sql-friendly method
3- The files to be indexed are PDF, MS Office, TXT
3- I'm also using an OCR to render received fax docs into text files and now i'm thinking about using the OCR to render text from any picture entered in the database and use that text to provide an index string for pictures as well.
4- The ability to provide different search results for different forms of the same word. i.e. searching for "international" & "internationalization" should return different results
5- The main tools i am interested in:

- Rendering text by iTextSharp and then feeding it to Lucene to get the index string (is it the best way to use Lucene?)

  Using adobe iFilter, although i'm not sure if this is enough for all the file types in my system

  Using SQL FTS. Is it strong enough to handle indexing the content of the files and perform complex search operations?

  Any other suggestions about other tools are very welcome as long as they provide better functionality

Examples, Tutorials and links are most appreciated :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've used Lucene for indexing PDF and other documents; it's pretty great.

[Indexing PDF Documents with Lucene](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2008/08/indexing-pdf-documents-with-lucene.html)

[Index Office files with Lucene](http://www.acidum.de/2009/01/07/index-microsoft-office-files-with-lucene/)

Lucene doesn't support word stemming (point 4), so those two words will return different results; the problem is if you want those two search terms to return the same resuls.